# Node Modules are not visible in my Git project in VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops, node-modules, spfx

I am new to VSTS. I have created a new SPFx webpart in sharepoint and it depends on Node Modules. I have tried to commit my changes to a project in VSTS. However, I do not see files node modules when I clone it on a different computer and so I am unable to do a gulp-serve on that computer. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you don't include referenced modules in GIT, instead, you fire command "npm install" before running the app to download them. Usually, there is a line in .tfignore file avoiding uploading those files.

Answer (score 1):

**It’s caused by the `node_modules` folder are ignored in `.gitignore` file.**

And `node_modules` truly should not add to git repo (source control) since the dependencies will be download automacatically when you execute `npm install`.

And you can check the example [sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts), the content for [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/.gitignore) file also contains `node_modules`.